# jQuery vs Vuejs Form management best practice

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm moving to Vue.js, and I have some trouble to manage Forms:

With a standard form with several fields, in jQuery environment when needing to avoid "save" button, I was used to save each field value via Ajax using on.keyup + debouncing

Now I moved to Vuejs+Vuetify and I'm wondering if the "old" solution is still the best solution,
or, for example, since form fields are populated via state, it is better to simply mutate the state and sync the database sending the state (or part of it) only when leaving the page?

If "old" solution is still preferable.. how can I get, together with the value, the name of the input field that triggered the @input?

since I was wondering to use watch, but that require to list all input field names, while I would have it as dynamic

Here just example of form:

```html
    <v-form ref="form">
      <v-row>
        <v-col md="6" cols="12">
          <v-text-field
            label="UserName"
            v-model="form.username"
            :error-messages="fieldErrors('form.username')"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col md="6" cols="12">
          <v-text-field
            label="Email"
            :value="form.email"
            :error-messages="fieldErrors('form.email')"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-form>
```

Comment: What library are you using ? Because `v-form` , `v-text-field` and so on does not come from vue natively

Comment: I wrote: ..Now I moved to Vuejs+Vuetify are Vuetify tags

Comment: Vue, just like jQuery, is unopinionated and flexible. At core, your question has nothing to do with either of them and it's about app architecture. Your question, if answered, is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts, which makes it off-topic here. In short, there is no best practice and it's more dependent on your specific use-case (the business logic of your app and the role of the form in its flow) than anything else.

Comment: To give you a better angle: nowadays one of the best approaches possible is to use PWA. Your store should act as a backend and allow the user to work regardless of network connection (and backend availability) and, when the network connection becomes available again, it should silently update the db. It's cool and good, but it takes more development effort. Is it worth it? How could we answer if we don't know the use-case?